# Extracting xyz coordinates from DGM file using gdal2xyz (I want the x and y coordinates in degrees not meters)

Tags: qgis

I am new to using QGIS and I am trying to compare elevation information between measured points using a total station and elevation given by the DGM files. The elevation comparison will occur in matlab. My problem is that the total station information gives the x and y coordinates in degrees/minutes and using the gdal2xyz in QGIS is only allowing me to extract the x and y coordinates in meters. This prevents me from directly comparing the points taken by the Total Station with the points in the DGM since the x and y coordinate are in degree/minutes and meters respectively.

My question is:

Is there a way to extract the xyz coordinates from the DGM file so that the x and y coordinates are shown in degrees/minutes and not in meters? if not, does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: You can transform the DGM to any CRS you need and then extract the xyz-data. Or you compare directly in QGIS.

Comment: the coordinate system I need is the WGS84, which is the CRS used during the total station measurements. my problem is that the x and y values are given in meters when extracted and not in degrees/minutes, and I need them in degrees/minutes.

Comment: Please expand what you mean by "extract", and/or what data type you intend to use in matlab.

Comment: so this is an example of a point measured by the total station:

$GPGGA,082119.00,5304.003272,N,00850.11050,E,4,10,1.2,-2.43,M,46.45,M,2.0,4095*59

the third and fifth column are the lat and long but in decimal degrees and minutes.

When i use the gdal2xyz function in QGIS, I get a CSV table with the following format:

490000.000 5880000.000 6.02

which is basically x y and z in meters. I cannot compare the elevations of the points measured on field and the points from the DGM because the first set has degrees and minutes as coordinates and the second set has coordinates in meters.

Comment: It is self-evident you can't compare that, since they're two different CRS, no need to point it out thrice. Which data type is your DGM?

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, I just got a matlab code that is able to convert ll to utm and vice versa. the data type of my DGM is float32 Gtiff. As I said, I am a total beginner so you have to take it easy on me. I would still like to know if it's possible to get lat long and altitude as a CSV table from a certain layer directly from QGIS.

Comment: Easiest way to compare your data would be to load the stations into QGIS, then use the SAGA tool `add raster values to points` to add your DGM-heights to the stations directly.